# Laravel Eloquent Saving Behavior

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it normal behavior that Laravel requires you to save a parent model before saving a `hasMany` relationship? I am able to use `belongsTo` before the model is saved.

```
    $team = new Team();
    $team->tournament()->associate($tournament);
    // $team->save(); without this line, it will throw an error

    $team->players()->save(new TeamPlayer([
        'user_id' => 1
    ]));
    $team->save();
```

The Team model's relationships looks like this:

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamPlayer::class);
}

public function tournament()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tournament::class);
}
```

The error that is thrown is this

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'team_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `team_players` (`user_id`, `team_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, , 2017-12-18 13:32:29, 2017-12-18 13:32:29))
```

Comment: In this case, yes.  players requires a team_id, which isn't generated if you save the players before you save the team.

Comment: I think you can use `create` instead of `save` to temporarily attach the TeamPlayer, and once you call `save()` on the team, I think it will recursively call `save` to all its current relations. Or call push on the `team`. Src: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_push